# Can I run a flavor of Ubuntu with a i7–3540M, 16GB RAM, and a SSD?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Thinkpad T430 with a i7–3540M processor, 16 GBs of RAM, and a solid state hard drive.  Can I run a flavor of Ubuntu on this laptop?  If so, which Ubuntu flavor should I install?

I could not find this information in any of the help files or the laptop help files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Your hardware is more than sufficient to run any currently supported version and flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)   *You can use the Try Ubuntu with all flavors of Ubuntu as well; most flavors are lighter than Ubuntu Desktop, but your hardware will run all, just as my 2008 dell desktop using a c2q-9400 will*

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Which flavour to install is very personal. Use Ventoy to put more than one .iso on a usb device, That way you can run each flavour in live mode and see which one you like the most. You don't have to worry about how heavy ( or ot ) the Desktop Environment is, since you have plenty of resources.